# How to create an slideshow in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I.m trying to get my slideshow to work. The first image fadein and fadeout, but after that all the other images wont show up. I'm using Notepad++ just in case you guys need to know that. Please can anyone help with this. I'm sure its a small mistake, i just can't find it. Thank you in advanced

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rwandan Genocide Gallery</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="images.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Slider(){

$(".slider #1").fadeIn(500);

$(".slider #1").delay(3000).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

var counter=$(".slider img").length();
var count=2;

setInterval(function(){
$(".slider #"+count).fadeIn(500);
$(".slider #"+count).delay(3000).hide("slide",{direction:"left"},500);

if(count == counter){
count = 1;
}
else
{
count = count+1;
},4000);

}

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Slider();">



<div class="slider">
<img id="1" src="images/genocide1.jpg" alt="image number 1"/>       
<img id="2" src="images/genocide5.jpg" alt="image number 4"/>   
<img id="3" src="images/genocide2.jpg" alt="image number 5"/>   
<img id="4" src="images/genocide11.jpg" alt="image number 6"/>  
</div>      



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use that jQuery plugin called [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) for slideshows.
It's much more better and less problematic.
Don't waste the time when you have got ready solutions.

Answer (score -1):

You had a few typing errors in your Slider function, take note of my comments to see what was wrong:

```
function Slider ()
{
    $(".slider #1").fadeIn(500);

    $(".slider #1").delay(3000).hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500);

    var counter = $(".slider img").length; // This should be a property, not a function.
    var count = 2;

    setInterval(function ()
    {
        $(".slider #" + count).fadeIn(500);
        $(".slider #" + count).delay(3000).hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 500);

        if (count == counter) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }, 4000); // You were passing the interval time to the end of the else.
}
```

Comment: can I fadeIn from one of the directions,lets say from left to rigth

Comment: @user3513160 Unfortunately you can not with `fadeIn`.